# Jekyll deployed in github shows raw text of index.html file

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, blogs

I am trying to deploy the Jekyll website using the forked repo from https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy theme. On my local system, all works fine. I have followed through all the instructions given in https://chirpy.cotes.page/posts/getting-started/#deployment and all appears to be ok. Even Github build status also indicates that the site is up and running at https://wxguy.github.io. However, when I access https://wxguy.github.io from firefox, The following line is displayed:-

```
--- layout: home # Index page ---
```

This is the exact content of the `index.html` located at the root of the project. I have renamed the `index.html` to `index.md` and deployed it again to GitHub. But still, the problem persists.

Next, I copied the content of `_layouts/home.html` to `index.html` again pushed it to GitHub. This time, it only displayed the text of Front Matter.

From the message I received on the firefox, it appears that GitHub is not building Jekyll site properly. I have deployed my site on the master branch in the remote.

I have gone through other blog source files which use the same theme at https://github.com/v3rtumnus/jekyll-blog. I am not able to figure out if any major changes I made to any configuration files.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the issue solved by doing the following:-

1. The theme I am using uses GitHub action and hence I have to configure it under GitHub/username/username.io/settings --> Actions --> General --> Scroll down the page to select "Workflow Permissions" and "Read and write permissions".
2. Deploy your modified site to Github.
3. Go to again settings GitHub/username/username.io --> Check if the workflow is completed successfully. If not, then rerun the process.
4. Go to settings -- > Pages --> Select `gh-pages` as a branch and `/root` as a directory.
5. Wait for a few min and your site should be up and running.

I also found that there was an issue with the browser cache which was not allowing a new page to load from the server. Therefore, I opened the site in private mode.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: I can not find `gh-pages'` as a branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked for me just by completing step 2. But it seems like it's not recommended to deploy without Github Actions according to: https://chirpy.cotes.page/posts/getting-started/#manually-build-and-deploy

Answer (score 4):

[image]

change setting to deploy source = github actions