# Github-pages using Jekyll theme publishes as raw text of index.html file

Tags: github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I seem to have exactly the same problem as [Jekyll deployed in github shows raw text of index.html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72079476/jekyll-deployed-in-github-shows-raw-text-of-index-html-file) but the solution [sundar-ima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221360/sundar-ima) figured out isn't working for me.

I'm really new to this and am trying to complete this as part of an assignment (to create a blog post, no more!) so I'm sorry that I'm being utterly clueless. However, looking through other repos, the contents of my index.html are correct and the layout is derived from config files.

To summarise, I've followed the instructions for https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy and have my first site working locally. However, when I deploy on github, I just get the raw text of the index.html file. I've tried the .github\workflows\pages-deploy.yml that comes with the template and tried using Github actions to create .github\workflows\jekyll.yml workflow. I've set the Setting > Actions > General > Workflow permissions to "Read and write permissions".

I'm quite lost and would really appreciate some pointers please.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/PenguinJunk/PenguinJunk.github.io.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your [build job](https://github.com/PenguinJunk/PenguinJunk.github.io/actions/runs/3976875139/jobs/6817632129), you can see that the build failed on `bundle install` with the following error:

```
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.5/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 5
```

I [see](https://github.com/PenguinJunk/PenguinJunk.github.io/commit/fabad91261efb8012542441523f3561c809394c1) that you already tried running `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`, which would've been my next recommendation as that seems to have worked for most people.

If you open the next section up in the build status, `bundle install`, you can see a different error message:

```
sass-embedded-1.57.1-x86_64-linux requires rubygems version >= 3.3.22, which is
incompatible with the current version, 3.2.33
```

Since this is the last error message displayed, it leads me to believe that the incompatibility is the cause of your issue here. If you can specify the version of `rubygems` to be `>= 3.3.22`, you should be good to go.

At the very least, now you know why you can't see your site; the action failed! Hope this solves your issue.